# Android use MQTT Socket Client in Background Thread in AppActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, mqtt

In our app, to communicate with the server we use MQTT Client. We use sockets only when the app is in Foreground mode, we may receive a lot of messages over Socket, thus we don't need to put Socket in Service.
How I can have the Socket Client in the background thread to send and receive messages, without freezing UI.

this is code of my Paho MQTT Socket Client:

```
mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), serverUri, clientId);
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {

                if (reconnect) {
                    addToHistory("Reconnected to : " + serverURI);
                    // Because Clean Session is true, we need to re-subscribe
                    subscribeToTopic();
                } else {
                    addToHistory("Connected to: " + serverURI);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                addToHistory("The Connection was lost.");
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                addToHistory("Incoming message: " + new String(message.getPayload()));
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Socket Client in Service is freezing UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758990/android-socket-client-in-service-is-freezing-ui)

Comment: You appear to have asked the same question twice, please only post once

Comment: In other question I asked how to use it in Service, in this question I am asking hot to use Socket in Background thread in AppActivity. I think questions are different.

Comment: @hardillb, Link is not working

Comment: Linked question was deleted